# Arcgis 10 vs Arcgis 9.3 data compatibility

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0

I have been doing some calculations such as slope in ArcGIS 9.3 but I needed to use ArcGIS 10 for fuzzy tool. My problem is when I open my data in ArcGIS 10, it shows me some wrong and extreme numbers like `-3*10^38` to `3*10^38` while it is supposed to be `0` to `84`.

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed in ArcGIS 10 SP1 (Due next month)

http://resources.arcgis.com/content/product-documentation?fa=viewDoc&PID=17&MetaID=1676

Answer (score -1):

Instead of saving as an `.mxd`, if you click "File > Share As > Map Package", you can work around issues like this.

Comment: In what way?  Please [edit] your answer to explain how this solves the problem.  Is Share As > Map Package available in 9.3?